# Find Duplicate Function names in different files

Tags: merge, refactoring, lisp, function-declaration, text-comparison

I have been merging all of source-code files used by various developers/CAD drafters for the past 15 or so years. It appears that everyone worked off the same code base until about 7 years ago, when everyone seems to have made a local copy of all the files and used/edited them locally.

I have successfully/painfully merged all of their files with the same names back together. However, I am finding that sometimes, files with different names contain functions with the same names and parameters. Tools that are expecting one implementation of a function may end up calling a different one depending on which files were loaded when.

Is there a simple way to search all of the files for repeated function names?

For Example, a function looks like this:

```
(defun MyInStr (SearchIn SearchFor)
    ...
)
```

How could I search all files for `(defun MyInStr (SearchIn SearchFor)`

Comment: What regex would identify function names?  Apply it to the entire code base, then find non-unique elements, then find files containing those elements.

Comment: Sounds great but IDK how to do regexes. could you give me an example using some information from my edit?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`ctags`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to generate the `TAGS` file, then searching it for duplicate lines:

```
$ ctags -R
$ sort TAGS -o - | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 '
```

The above will produce output like this:

```
...
3   defun MyInStr (SearchIn SearchFor)
...
```

which will tell you that `MyInStr` is re-defined 3 times in the codebase with the identical signature.

You can also extract just the function name using `sed` or do a more complicated processing of the `TAGS` file with `perl` or `lisp` or `python` any other scripting tool.

Comment: I successfully get a tags file. But when I run the second command there is no output

Comment: It means that there are no dupes. Do you understand how the command works? Basically, the `TAGS` file contains all the defuns from all the files - now you need to scan just one file.

Comment: No there are dupes. I made sure to add one myself. and I checked the tags file and see that they exist, but I dont get a nice printout like you describe `3   defun MyInStr (SearchIn SearchFor)` its as if your second command does nothing

Comment: Let me repeat: Do you understand how the command works? _When_ you do, you should be able to figure out how do modify it to suit your needs.  You should also grep `TAGS` for the function you added.